# JUnit4 test causes java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date

Tags: java, android, junit4, simpledateformat, parseexception

I can successfully execute the following code snippet in an Android project:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.US);
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = null;
try {
    date = dateFormat.parse("2015-08-17T19:30:00+02:00");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now I put the same code snippet into a JUnit4 test:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class DateUtilsTests {

    @Test
    public void testFailsWithParseException() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.US);
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = dateFormat.parse("2015-08-17T19:30:00+02:00");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assertThat(date).isNotEqualTo(null);
    }

}
```

This fails:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-08-17T19:30:00+02:00"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) Javadoc:

- `Z` corresponds to [RFC 822 time zone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone) (like `-0800`)
- `X` corresponds to  [ISO 8601 time zone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone) (like `-08` or `-0800` or `-08:00`)

In your case, you want to parse a timezone written in the form `+02:00` (i.e. with a colon between the hours and minutes) so you should use the `X` token instead of `Z`.

However, in Android, [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) doesn't have the `X` token, only `Z`, and the documentation states that `Z` supports parsing a timezone of the format `-08:00`.

Comment: Why is `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` behaving different in the Android context and in JUnit?

Comment: @JJD The class `SimpleDateFormat` is just not the same in the Android case.

Comment: So it is impossible to setup tests when the format pattern is defined in Android code?